# Is it possible to assign probability to a set $X$ with $|X|>2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

Is it possible to assign probability to a set $X$ with cardinality $|X| > 2^{\aleph_0}$? Example would be a set $|X| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: Take a point mass on $X$, with corresponding $\sigma$-algebra $2^X$.

Comment: If you are asking if the size of an underlying set of a probability measure space can be any infinite cardinal, the answer is clearly yes.  Perhaps you have something more difficult in mind?

Comment: Any finite measure on $X$ will give you a probability (after it's normalized).  It will certainly have large measure zero subsets.

Comment: @Stefan: As I pointed out, this question is not *really* about measurable cardinals. It's about defining a probability measure on a set larger than continuum.

Comment: @Asaf I agree that your interpretation of OP's intentions is more reasonable than mine. The excitement for large cardinals must have blended me ;-)

Comment: You can define product measures on the Baire subsets of $2^X$ for any set $X$. This is surely a more interesting measure than dirac measure. In some sense these are the only atomless probability spaces (a celebrated result of Maharam).

Comment: @hot_queen: Not sure why you haven't posted that answer already.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, I will. The only issue is that I am not sure what question is being asked here.

Comment: @hot_queen: As far as I understand it? Is it possible to have a probability space whose underlying set has size $>\frak c$.

Comment: I guess then dirac measures work for the OP unless atomic measures are undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

If you wonder why so far only the "trivial" example of a Dirac measure has been mentioned, there is actually a good reason for this. The young Ulam wondered whether there is an uncountable set $X$ for which there is a probability measure
$$
\mu \colon \mathcal P(X) \rightarrow [0,1]
$$
that vanishes on singletons (i.e. $\mu(\{x\})= 0$ for all $x \in X$).

He realized that even in the simpler case that such a $\mu$ is only 2-valued (so for all $Y \subseteq X$ either $\mu(Y) = 0$ or $\mu(Y) = 1$), we cannot prove in ZFC that such an $(X,\mu)$ exists. More precisely: Let $\kappa$ be the smallest cardinal of such an uncountable $X$. Then $\kappa$ is what we nowadays call a [*measurable cardinal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal). As such it is inaccessible and thus $V_\kappa \models \text{ZFC}$. By Gödel's incompleteness theorem, we therefore cannot prove that such a $\kappa$ exists (if ZFC is consistent).

Assuming the existence of a measurable cardinal allows us to prove results, that cannot be settled in ZFC alone (e.g. analytic determinacy) and in the last (5?,6?, even more?) decades much work has been done under the assumption of measurable (or other large) cardinals.

Comment: I don't see how the binary case it's simpler. Or how this actually answers the question, since having a set of size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ does not mean that we measure *all* the subsets of some $X$. We simply assign probability to some subsets which form a $\sigma$-algebra. Nobody requested it to be the entire power set, or two-valued.

Comment: @Asaf Isn't it also incorrect? Measurability means your ultra-filter on $\kappa$ is $\kappa$-complete, but of course we only need countably complete for a measure, not $\kappa$ complete, which must be weaker than the existence of a measurable?

Comment: "Simpler" may indeed be misleading, I probably should have written something like "even if we restrict ourselves to the case where $\mu$ is 2-valued" instead... And whether or not this answers the question? Well, I cannot tell as OP's question is pretty vague.

Comment: @James The smallest uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ for which there is a countably closed, non-trivial ultrafilter already carries a $<\kappa$-closed one.

Comment: @Stefan, set theory man, it's always surprising me.

Comment: @James: But a measure, in the set of measure theory is *not* an ultrafilter. Nothing in this answer is wrong (at best, the "simpler" is a bit misleading), but I just think it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Probability is not just defined on a set. It's also defined on a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets. Namely, a probability structure is made of three parts:

1. The underlying set, say $X$.
2. The sets to which you *can* assign probability.
3. The function which assigns probability.

There are several axioms which we require of these structures, such as the sets to which you assign the probability will form a $\sigma$-algebra, and that $\mu(X-A)=1-\mu(A)$ whenever $A$ is a set that can be assigned probability.

Naively we might want to be able to assign probability to *every* subset of $X$, but even in the case of $[0,1]$ with the usual probability, this is not always possible in the presence of the axiom of choice. More specifically, in the "classical" settings of probability, you can show that there are subsets of $[0,1]$ that you cannot assign a probability, if you want the probability of an interval to be its length.

Which is why we allow some sets not to have a probability. Some trivial possible ways to assign probability is to assign $0$ to any countable subset of $X$, and $1$ to any set $A$ which is co-countable, namely $X-A$ is countable. Others, as suggested are the Dirac measures which concentrate on a singleton, or some particular subset.

Answer (score 3):

For any cardinal $\kappa$, you can define the product measure on $2^{\kappa}$ where $0, 1$ are assigned one half measure each. This measure is defined on the sigma algebra generated by clopen subsets of $2^{\kappa}$. Let us call the corresponding measure algebra $\text{Random}(\kappa)$. The class of measure algebras thus obtained forms the building block for every atomless (probability) measure algebra in the following sense:

Theorem ([Maharam](http://www.pnas.org/content/28/3/108.full.pdf)): Every atomless (probability) measure algebra can be decomposed into countably many pieces each of which is isomorphic (modulo rescaling) to $\text{Random}(\kappa)$ for some $\kappa$.

Comment: The proof uses transfinite induction to construct maximal independent family of events. This should count as a nice use of transfinite induction :P.

Answer (score 1):

In general for any set $A$ is possible give the probability of dirac, $i.e$ let $x\in X$ and $U\subset A$ we define $\delta_x(U)=1$ if $x\in U$ and $\delta_x(U)=0, \, else.$  so Always is possible give a measure of probability of any set.